# How can I find the log 2 base of a double variable?

Tags: java, class, math, methods

I'm trying to calculate the log 2 base of some double form numbers but it seems that there isn't a standard method from a libraly for that.

I tried out this code,error occurs though.

```
        double entropy=0;
        for(int i=0; i<26;i++){
            entropy+=-possibilityCounter[i]*log2(possibilityCounter[i]);
        }
```

NOTE: possibilityCounter table is full of double variables e.g 0.00133536

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can calculate the log base 2 from the natural log like this

```
public double log2(double v) {
    return Math.log(v) / Math.log(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed in `java.util.Math` you have logs for base `e` and `10`.

However you can use the following formula:

```
log2(x) = log(x)/log(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
double entropy = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    entropy += -possibilityCounter[i] * Math.log(possibilityCounter[i]) / Math.log(2);
}
```